# Commercial spectrometer driver (Omnidriver) extremely slow on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, linux

I'm trying to use C++ program read data form a spectrometer, which has a commercial spectrometer driver named Omnidriver. The driver is developed in Java. The installer of this driver will install version 1.6.0_01 (1.6 update 1) of the Java JVM. To develop in C++, I install JDK 14 myself.

The code is simple:

```
  define LINUX
  #include <iostream>
  #include <WrapperLinux64.h>
  #include <Wrapper.h>
  #include <ArrayTypes.h>
   
  int main(){
  
          Wrapper wrapper;
          ***code to read***
          return(0);
  }
```

Then I compile the code like this

```
/usr/bin/g++ -std=c++14 -O2 -Wall   -I ~/Programs/OmniDriver/include -I /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-14.0.2 -L /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-14.0.2/lib -I ~/Programs/ROOT/include -I /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-14.0.2/include -I /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-14.0.2/include/linux main.cxx -o main ~/OmniDriver/OOI_HOME/libOmniDriver.so ~/Programs/OmniDriver/OOI_HOME/libcommon.so -ljvm
```

It can be simplified as:

```
g++ -std=c++14 -O2 (-ggdb3) -Wall -I /path main.cxx -o main -L lib.so -ljvm
```

The code can be compiled, but when I run it, it's extremely slow. It should be done is 3 seconds but it takes 10 minutes.

The first part of the output is like this:

```
Linux native USB library loaded.
NatUSB
Detected device change on USB
```

Then it takes 2 minutes to get:

```
The interface was claimed successfully.
```

and then another few minutes to read data from spectrometer.

I'm a newbie and I fail to solve this problem even I try my best. Could you please give me some advice?

Comment: Since all time is spent in the vendor's code, contact their support first. You could try running your program under strace to see what it is doing in those dead moments, but since you're paying for support, better use it. Do you get the same slowdown if you use the bundled JDK?

Comment: @Botje I thought I am already using the bundled JDK! The compiler ask for jni.h header file so I include the JDK 14 path. I'm not sure what I'm doing actually!

Comment: Your question text states that "The installer of this driver will install version 1.6.0_01 (1.6 update 1) of the Java JVM". So does it make a difference if you build/link against that instead of OpenJDK 14? It is probably the first thing the vendor will ask of you.

Comment: @Botje I checked again and I find the bundled JVM is only JVM, no JDK. There is no header file inside.

Comment: @Botje I already tried that. I can't tell the difference.

Comment: Fair enough. Then strace your program, see if you find anything suspicious, and either update your question or contact the vendor.

Comment: @Botje Thank you! I already find something wrong by strace! It seems that something is wrong with usb permission. I'll try more and then update the question.